# rails radio buttons too far away

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

Not sure if this is a rails problem or a css problem.

I generated radio buttons using `form_for`, but the radio buttons are too far away from the question and ignore the constraints of the parent element. You can see the radio button's behavior in the snippet. How do I fix this?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-8 col-md-offset-1 color-it'>
      <div class="questions">
        <label for="submitted_quiz_Quiz 1 Question 1">Quiz 1 question 1</label>
        <input value="4" type="hidden" name="submitted_quiz[submitted_answers_attributes][0][question_id]" id="submitted_quiz_submitted_answers_attributes_0_question_id" />
        <div class='options'>
          <div class='radio'>
            <input class="quiz-radio" type="radio" value="Quiz 1 Question 1 Answer 1" name="submitted_quiz[submitted_answers_attributes][0][content]" id="submitted_quiz_submitted_answers_attributes_0_content_quiz_1_question_1_answer_1" />
            <label class="quiz-radio-answer" for="submitted_quiz_submitted_answers_attributes_0_content_quiz_1_question_1_answer_1">Quiz 1 question 1 answer 1</label>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

if you want the rails `fields_for` used to generate this, here it is:

```
<%= f.fields_for (:submitted_answers) do |ff| %>

<%= ff.hidden_field :question_id, :value => question.id %>
<div class = 'options'>
<% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
<div class = 'radio'>
<%= ff.radio_button :content, answer.content, :class => 'quiz-radio' %>
<%= ff.label :content, :value => answer.content, :class => 'quiz-radio-answer' %>



</div>
<% end #answer.each do %>

</div>
<% end #fields_for (:submitted_answers) do %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there is a default style is applying from boostrap css

**boostrap.css**

```
.checkbox label, .radio label {
    min-height: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

so u have to overwrite u can use the new class **custom-radio** near by **radio** class

```
<div class='radio custom-radio'>
            <input class="quiz-radio" type="radio" value="Quiz 1 Question 1 Answer 1" name="submitted_quiz[submitted_answers_attributes][0][content]" id="submitted_quiz_submitted_answers_attributes_0_content_quiz_1_question_1_answer_1" />
            <label class="quiz-radio-answer" for="submitted_quiz_submitted_answers_attributes_0_content_quiz_1_question_1_answer_1">Quiz 1 question 1 answer 1</label>

          </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .custom-radio label {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
}

.custom-radio input[type=radio] {
   margin-left: 0px !important; 
}
```

Comment: hi that moved the radio labels closer to the radio button but the radio button itself is still in the same place as before. Any ideas?

Comment: check my updated one i added one more CSS .custom-radio input[type=radio] {
   margin-left: 0px !important; 
}

Comment: just adding the second one fixed it for me, thanks! As a side note, input[type=radio] is something unfamiliar to me, I haven't seen this in css before. Do you have a link that mentions it?

Comment: if its working please mark the above ans for other peoples refrence

Comment: for refrence http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_form.asp